# Give logger object as a parmeter when importing a module

Tags: python, logging, import

Let me describe the following scenario :

I'm using a module of my own in a few projects. This module holds classes and additional sub modules (again of my own).

I want to write log messages in the module and its sub files, but give the logger object as a parameter when importing the module in each project.

All the loggers I am using have similar interface (same mthods etc...).

Is there a way to implement this concept?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing logger object as param to module, you can use universal function that returns needed logger based on loggers's id. It's how logging system implemented in standard Python [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) module.

`logging.getLogger(name=None)` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger)) uses to get logger object, based on given name. Usually `name` is module name: `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.

In case you don't want to use standard `logging`, you can at least use this concept in your projects.

In logging module:

```
loggers = {}

def get_logger(name):
    if name not in loggers:
        loggers[name] = Logger()  # create logger instance for name
    return loggers[name]
```

In projects:

```
import get_logger  # use this function in projects to get logger instances

logger = get_logger("project 1 logger id")  # in project 1
logger = get_logger("project 2 logger id")  # in project 2
```